# Resetting Row_Number after X number of days have occurred from an anchored point

Tags: t-sql

I've searched through SO and haven't seen this Q come up so am trying it.

I have a dataset that has names and dates.  What I'd like to do is reset my row_number count once 30 days have passed starting from an anchor point.  Then that row becomes the new anchor point until another row occurs 30 days after.  Rinse and Repeat.  Please note, I am not trying to find a point every 30 days, it needs to be 30 days from the anchor.

```
Create table test_D (
name_test char(10),
date_test datetime
);

INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-100, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-86, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-77, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-64, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-44, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-27, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-15, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-2, getdate())); 

INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-130, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-96, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-73, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-61, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-44, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-37, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-24, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-12, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO test_D VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-3, getdate())); 


IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ck1')IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #ck1
select * , row_number() over (partition by name_test order by date_test) as rno, dateadd(DAY, 30, date_test) as target_date
into #ck1
from test_D

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#ck2')IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #ck2
select c.* , c2.rno as target_rnum, row_number() over (partition by c.name_test, c.rno order by c2.rno) as keeper, case when c.rno = 1 then 1 else 0 end as marker_test 
into #ck2
from #ck1 c
left join #ck1 c2 on c.name_test = c2.name_test and c2.date_test >= c.target_date


select *
from #ck2
where keeper = 1


update c
set marker = 1
from #ck2 c
where 1=1
and name_test = 'x'
and rno = 4


update c
set marker = 1
from #ck2 c
where 1=1
and name_test = 'x'
and rno = 6
```

....etc

I can achieve this by running like 5 or 6 temp tables and left joining and re-row_number()'ing, but there must be a better more succinct way to do this.  Am I over-looking any functions that would make this task easier?

I am using MS SQL v14

output desired:

| name_test | date_test | RowNumber |
| --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2021-02-03 16:27:40.990 | 1 |
| x | 2021-02-17 16:27:40.990 | 2 |
| x | 2021-02-26 16:27:41.007 | 3 |
| x | 2021-03-11 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| x | 2021-03-31 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| x | 2021-04-17 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| x | 2021-04-29 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| x | 2021-05-12 16:27:41.007 | 3 |
| y | 2021-01-04 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| y | 2021-02-07 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| y | 2021-03-02 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| y | 2021-03-14 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| y | 2021-03-31 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| y | 2021-04-07 16:27:41.007 | 3 |
| y | 2021-04-20 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| y | 2021-05-02 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| y | 2021-05-11 16:27:41.007 | 3 |

Comment: Can you provide sample data and how you want the results to appear.

Comment: @WesH, sample data provided, it's just based off getdate() which is fine - does not matter what day you run the inserts on since the days are spaced apart to ensure proper classification.   I did add a sample output, but the dates will change depending on when someone created their sample data.   If that makes things confusing I can update the sample data to hardcoded values.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're determining your starting anchor point but, in my solution below, I used the `MIN(date_test)` value to get your earliest date.

Using that date as your starting anchor, you can use `FLOOR(DATEDIFF())` and divide by 30 to bucket your rows into 30-day increments from that anchor date.  Then you can use your `ROW_NUMBER` as planned which will start over with a new row number for each of the 30-day buckets.

```
declare @anchor datetime
select @anchor = min(date_test) 
from test_D

;with increment30
as (
    select *, floor(datediff(dd,@anchor,date_test)/30.00) + 1 as increment
    from test_D
    ), resetRN
    as (
        select *, row_number() over (partition by increment order by date_test) rn
        from increment30
        )
select *
from resetRN
order by date_test
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work - ex. for name group y, March 12th is marked correctly, however the next group should start at April 18th not April 5th since the 5th is less than 30 days from March 12th.    It's a correct assumption to begin with the min date for each name, but the next anchor point doesn't start until at least 30 days from the new point.  Not the first point in every 30 day grouping.  Thanks for taking a shot!

Comment: So each anchor point is based on the next date that falls OUTSIDE of the previous window?  So for example, if Anchor #1 is March 12th but the next date past April 12th (i.e. outside of the Anchor #1 30-day window) is not until May 1st, then Anchor #2 would be May 1st?

Comment: Correct...sorry if that wasn't clear in my initial post

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variables to remember the last anchored point and change it if on of the following conditions are met:

- The current partitioning condition (name_test) is different from the previous partitioning condition => New anchored point needed
- The `dateddiff` is greater then the defined 30 Days.

The feature we are exploiting are that we can update simultaneously both the table and the variable, and we can force the sql engine to perform the update of a single row at a time.

```
if object_id('tempdb.dbo.#test_D') is not null drop table #test_D
    create table #test_D (name_test char(10),date_test datetime, anchored_date datetime)

INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-100, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-86, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-77, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-64, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-44, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-27, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-15, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-130, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('x', dateadd(day,-2, getdate())); 

INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-96, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-73, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-61, getdate()));  
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-44, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-37, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-24, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-12, getdate())); 
INSERT INTO #test_D( name_test, date_test) VALUES('y', dateadd(day,-3, getdate())); 

declare @prev_name_test char(10) = ''
declare @prev_anchored_date datetime = '19000101'

; with test as (select top 100 percent td.name_test, td.date_test, td.anchored_date from #test_D td order by td.name_test, td.date_test)
update td
set
    @prev_anchored_date = case
        when td.name_test <> @prev_name_test then td.date_test
        when datediff(day, @prev_anchored_date, td.date_test) > 30 then td.date_test
        else @prev_anchored_date
    end
    , @prev_name_test = name_test
    , td.anchored_date = @prev_anchored_date 
from test td
option(maxdop 1)

select
    td.name_test
    , td.date_test
    , td.anchored_date  
    , row_number() over (partition by td.name_test, td.anchored_date order by td.date_test) RowNumber
from
    #test_D td
```

I am not sure that the `FLOOR(DATEDIFF())` is needed to round the dates, but if it is, you can add it in the case above.

Output:

| name_test | date_test | anchored_date | RowNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 2021-02-03 16:27:40.990 | 2021-02-03 16:27:40.990 | 1 |
| x | 2021-02-17 16:27:40.990 | 2021-02-03 16:27:40.990 | 2 |
| x | 2021-02-26 16:27:41.007 | 2021-02-03 16:27:40.990 | 3 |
| x | 2021-03-11 16:27:41.007 | 2021-03-11 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| x | 2021-03-31 16:27:41.007 | 2021-03-11 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| x | 2021-04-17 16:27:41.007 | 2021-04-17 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| x | 2021-04-29 16:27:41.007 | 2021-04-17 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| x | 2021-05-12 16:27:41.007 | 2021-05-12 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| y | 2021-01-04 16:27:41.007 | 2021-01-04 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| y | 2021-02-07 16:27:41.007 | 2021-02-07 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| y | 2021-03-02 16:27:41.007 | 2021-02-07 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| y | 2021-03-14 16:27:41.007 | 2021-03-14 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| y | 2021-03-31 16:27:41.007 | 2021-03-14 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| y | 2021-04-07 16:27:41.007 | 2021-03-14 16:27:41.007 | 3 |
| y | 2021-04-20 16:27:41.007 | 2021-04-20 16:27:41.007 | 1 |
| y | 2021-05-02 16:27:41.007 | 2021-04-20 16:27:41.007 | 2 |
| y | 2021-05-11 16:27:41.007 | 2021-04-20 16:27:41.007 | 3 |

Comment: This looks close, but for x, 5/12 shouldn't be a reset.  It's less than 30 days from 4/17.  Thanks for taking a shot!  But this does give me an idea using variables and a while loop...